# Unable to find IPFS (JS)

Tags: node.js, ipfs

[image]I installed ipfs and it is working in the terminal. But when i wrote a small js code, it is not working. The error is as shown in the image below.

Comment: did u install it using `-g` flag?

Comment: yes i installed with -g flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install a package using the global(-g) flag then you have to link it to your local workspace before using. But my recommendation will be add the package in `package.json` by installing the package locally again.

do:

```
go to your local folder:

npm i <package_name> --save
```

Or to link:

```
go to your local folder:

npm link <package_name>
```